# What does the different Thunderbird folder icons mean?

Tags: thunderbird

Does anybody know what the different Thunderbird folder icons mean?

I have some blue folders which I cannot delete where the yellow ones can be removed.

[image]

Comment: No sorry, images can only be posted if my reputation is >= 10

Comment: ;-) I've add a screen shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from memory (I have Thunderbird installed at home - but I'm not at home to double check).

The "postage stamp" icon represents folders associated with identities. The "Sent Items" folder is where outgoing e-mails from your default identity get sent.

Do have any other identities set up that have a different folder associated with them?

**Update**

Sorry for the delay - but the "postage stamp" icon does represent those folders where you've set up an identity to place a copy in that folder rather than "Sent" when sending e-mails.

I would have thought that it **should** be that when you delete that identity the folder reverts to the normal icon. However, I've just tested this on Thunderbird 3.1.7 on Windows and the "postage stamp" remains both when the "place copy option" is reset and when the identity is deleted. A search of the registry didn't reveal anything and there doesn't appear to be anything in the mail folders that identifies these folders as something special.

It looks like it's a bug.

Comment: Yes, before I had some extra identities which copied their messages to that folders. But I already removed these identities form TB

Comment: @waanders - try restarting Thunderbird. I know it takes a restart going the other way (i.e. setting up an identity to use a folder).

Comment: I did. One identity was removed months ago, I restarted TB hunderds of times after that ;-)

Comment: @waanders - ah. In that case I'll have to leave it until I get home tonight to check further.

Comment: Anybody any idea?

Comment: @waanders - sorry I completely forgot. I'll try to remember and check tonight.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Although not completely satisfied with the answer (I think I will have to live with it) I marked the question as Answered.

Comment: @waanders - I can understand why you're not satisfied, but unfortunately that's the way Thunderbird appears to be at the moment.

Comment: Sure, it's not your fault ;-)

Comment: The only way is maybe backup all messages and identities with e.g. MozBackup, deinstall TB and reinstall TB and import the messages and identities again with MozBackup...

Comment: I'd like to mention that this is still an existing bug in the system. I'll take a look and see if it was ever reported.

Comment: `Submitted` https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=892637

Answer (score 3):

I discovered how to delete this folder once the original identity associated with it is gone.

i created a new account, and specified sent mail to be sent to this folder. I think I closed T-bird, then re-opened, although this might not be required. Then I changed this folder setting BACK to sending sent mail to a DIFFERENT folder, and the postage stamp icon changed back to a regular yellow folder which can be deleted. Then I deleted the account I made to make all of this possible.

An inelegant explanation and probably a couple of extra steps, but it worked.

Comment: Excellent! A workaround, but yes it works. Thanks a lot!